# Выборка строки таблицы с названием текущего дня недели

Tags: mysql

есть таблица типа:

```
Название таблицы[...] [monday][tuesday][wednesday][thursday][friday][saturday][sunday][...]
Значения        [...] [0]     [1]      [0]        [1]       [0]     [1]       [1]     [...]
```

Мне нужно в запросе выбрать тут колонку которая совпадает с текущим названиями дня недели `DAYNAME(CURDATE())` и проверить равно значение 1 или 0, не могу понять как мне выбирать именно ту колонку которая совпадает с названиям текущего дня недели.

Кто подсказать может?)

Comment: скорее всего имя поля нужно будет получить вне MySQL

Comment: Обычным запросом это сделать невозможно. В SQL любые имена (таблиц, колонок) должны быть заданы явно. Не, ну конечно с извратами можно вроде `case (dayofweek(now()) when 1 then sunday when 2 then monday ... end`. Но я бы смотрел в сторону изменения структуры таблицы, что бы была одна колонка с номером дня недели и много записей

Comment: @Mike нужна операция обратная PIVOT. тогда можно без явного названия. я делал на postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE) 
            WHEN 1 THEN `sunday`
            WHEN 2 THEN `monday`
            WHEN 3 THEN `tuesday`
            WHEN 4 THEN `wednesday`
            WHEN 5 THEN `thursday`
            WHEN 6 THEN `friday`
            WHEN 7 THEN `saturday`
            ELSE NULL
            END, <остальные поля>
FROM ...
```

ну или та же конструкция во WHERE или где там её надо...

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно!

Comment: @Akina Восхищаюсь Вашими знаниями в `sql` и скоростью ответов )